# Reset form input

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has two parts to it.
Yes or No.

Yes if you were present (Shows a div)

No if you were absent (Show a div)

What i'm trying to get do is that if the user selects No and selects any input and then decides to go back to **Yes** i need to reset the value of any item in **No** back to the form default.

Thank you

My fiddle is below for a visual experience..

http://jsfiddle.net/5nTsk/4/

Comment: you have duplicate IDs (btnyes)... Related to the question, I would build all the logic of the reset on a function and then call it via the click on the yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this simple function:

```
function defaultNo(){
    $("#getmytimetaken select").val("0").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

and place it at the click:

```
if($(this).val() == "getmytimeregular") defaultNo();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5nTsk/7/

P.S. of course you don't even need the function, but it could be handy to use it on other situations, like a reset button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Javascript's [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) method.

Here's an example that will reset the first form of a page (using jQuery's [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)):

```
$('form').get(0).reset();
```

On Stackoverflow, this is the searchbox (you can try using the console of Firebug/ChromeDevTools).

You can then manually reselect Yes/No if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to reset the entire form you can go with middus answer.

Or else if you need to reset a portion of your page then you can use:

```
$(':input','#mycontainer')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

This will only reset the input elements that are children of mycontainer. And this should do the trick.